# jQuery - is there shortern notation for the following statement?

Tags: jquery

I want to select elements that have similar incrementally-based names. Is there shorter notation to do the same thing?

```
$('#galnav1,#galnav2,#galnav3,#galnav4,#galnav5,#galnav6,#galnav7,#galnav8,#galnav9,').each(function(){
    ... 
});
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you didn't just gave them the same class?

Comment: Sometimes you need to select just one and you need to know exactly which, other times you want all of them, good question

Comment: @Greg Flynn: it is not a justification for not having a common class for all of them

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this one:

```
$('[id^=galnav]');

$('[id^=galnav]').filter(function() {
    return /v\d$/.test($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

Comment: Will that also catch #galnav10? Is there some way of saying something like [id+galnav(1..9)] ?

Comment: @Owen: added probable solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use this jquery selector

```
$('[id^="galnav"]').each(function(){
    ... 
});
```